angular - main.js ends up in Lazy Chunk files
I have two projects with very similar setup. Both following the NX monorepo structure and setup, I've done couple of migrations from older version to a newer one, and I noticed that in one of the apps, the main.js is always shown in the Lazy Chunk Files category in the build log:
Initial chunk files           | Names         |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
polyfills.45732861e6a6851d.js | polyfills     |  34.19 kB |                11.03 kB

                              | Initial total |  34.19 kB |                11.03 kB

Lazy chunk files              | Names         |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
main.css, main.js             | main          | 277.90 kB |                49.44 kB
runtime.a9fc7548b14f6ea7.js   | runtime       |   1.06 kB |               587 bytes

where the other App is showing correctly:
Initial chunk files           | Names                                       |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
main.2b3b603cebbde51f.js      | main                                        |   1.30 MB |               276.63 kB
polyfills.fefcd4772972c304.js | polyfills                                   |  34.19 kB |                11.04 kB

it even has the hash at the end of file name. Where the first one is missing, which is typical for lazy-loaded chunks. But why would main.js be marked as lazy loaded chunk? Any ideas?
I've compared all the configs, removed any references to lazy-loaded modules, but still no success whatsoever. I'm just hoping that someone might have experienced similar behavior and point me to right direction.
Angular version 18.x
Nx version 19.x
main.ts
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

project.json build config
"
optimization": {
            "scripts": true,
            "styles": {
              "minify": true,
              "inlineCritical": false
            },
            "fonts": true
          },
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "progress": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          ]

app.module.ts
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
    ],
    providers: [
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}

no routes applied, I removed it all..

can you provide app.routes.ts?

actually I completely removed that too, it's just plain app.module.ts with one component.

Turned out it was actually the styles config.
      {
        "input": "styles/main.scss",
        "bundleName": "main",
        "inject": false
      },

the budnleName in the styles field was actually set to the same name as is given to main.js during the build process.
Once I renamed it, all seem to be working now
Initial chunk files           | Names         |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
main.40b5bf56ef660341.js      | main          |  78.80 kB |                23.61 kB
polyfills.e300f3421dd24755.js | polyfills     |  34.19 kB |                11.04 kB

